# How to show that belonging to a set implies belonging to another set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For the first time in my life, I'm trying to come up with a small proposition to be formally proved. I've been working on it for months now, and I have been able to do several steps. Yet, I've been stuck in the last step for several weeks now. In fact, I'm starting to hesitate if what I want to show is even true. Hence, could this great community help me with the last step I'm stuck with? Let me now introduce you my problem formally.

*Consider three elements $i,j,k$ and three sets $S,S^{\prime},S^{\prime\prime}$. Further, let us assume:*

*(**1**) $j \in S^{\prime}$ or $k \in S^{\prime}$ or $j,k \in S^{\prime}$;*

*(**2**) $i \in S^{\prime}$ for sure;*

*(**3**) $i \notin S^{\prime\prime}$ for sure;*

*(**4**) $S^{\prime} \cap S^{\prime\prime} \neq \emptyset$ for sure;*

*(**5**) $i \in S$ for sure.*

*The statement to be shown is as follows: if $j \in S \cap S^{\prime\prime}$, then $j \in S^{\prime\prime} \backslash S^{\prime}$.*

Could please anyone help me? Thank you all very much for your time and effort.

PS: I've mainly tried to show that $j \in S$ must imply that $j \notin S^{\prime}$, but with null success. Probably, it's not that simple or I'm missing some assumptions

PS2: If the question is too localised or does not fit the purposes of the community properly, please let me know how I can improve it and I'll try to do so.

Comment: Comment: what about $k$ ? It is not prsent in the sought conclusion...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know: so far, it's just there to make sure that we are only dealing with a case of $3$ elements and $3$ sets. It may be the case that I need to say something about $k$ to show what I need, but if this is the case, I could not figure it out on my own.

Comment: The same for $i$ ...

Comment: If $j \in S \cap S''$ we have that both $j \in S$ and $j \in S''$.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. However, I'm not sure I'm getting your point, now.

Comment: Thus, in order to conclude that $j \in S'' \setminus S'$ we must have that $j \notin S'$.

Comment: But from (i) we have that it may be the case that $j \in S'$...

Comment: Exactly. So what I would like is to show that $j \notin S^{\prime}$, but I don't see how to do that with my current assumptions. So I understand that I should assume something else in order to discard $j \in S^{\prime}$ . But I don't see what. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false.

Take $$S=\{i, j\}, S'=\{i,j\}, S''=\{j\}$$

Then, it is easy to see that all your conditions are met, and also that $$j\in(S\cap S'')\land \neg (j\in S''\setminus S')$$

which means that the implication you want to prove is incorrect (because its negation is correct).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yet, I must acknowledge a mistake of mine because I forgot to include one assumption! I will edit my original question now. I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. See assumption *(**5**)*, if still interested.

Comment: @Héctor The statement is still false. I edited my answer.